Do PHP enums use shared memory like constant expressions?
My understanding is that constant expressions only use their memory allocation once.
For example:
class MyClass{

   const MY_ARRAY = [
      1 => 'One',
      2 => 'Two',
      3 => 'Three',
   ];
}

Let's assume that const array takes 20 bytes of memory. If there are 1000 instances of the same script running on the same server, the server will use only 20 bytes, not 20,000 bytes, because the const is stored by PHP in shared memory.
Now the PHP manual says that enums can be used in constant expressions. That would seem to imply that an enum must be evaluated at compile time like constant expressions are.
But the documentation doesn't specify if enums occupy shared memory, or if there is a memory cost for each script instance.
I'm looking for an authoritative answer on if enums are stored in shared memory, like class constants.

Every PHP script is it's own instance, shared nothing with its own memory. When you say 'constant expressions only use their memory allocation once' this is in relation to the lifetime of a single execution.

from https://wiki.php.net/rfc/enumerations: "Because cases are represented as constants on the enum itself, they may be used as static values in most constant expressions" and "Cloning of enum cases. Enum cases must be single instances in order to behave predictably"

Not shared.
PHP instances are separate, they're not sharing constants, nor enums, there's no such thing as "storing them only once on a server", all PHP processes will have their own little world, including constants. Shared memory is a different concept and it would take a performance overhead to use in this case; PHP would need to compare the shared version with the one being defined and only reuse it if it's the same. So it's cheaper to just use the constants in each instance.

Respectfully, this is not correct. Constant expressions defined with const are stored in shared memory.

@Nick – are you sure? Where's this information coming from? It would need a lot of housekeeping from php, I don't think anyone would implement such a pointless solution for constants. But I'm always eager to learn.
